# How can I merge Stack Overflow and Careers account?

Tags: discussion

I want to merge both my Stack Overflow and Careers (careers.stackoverflow.com/) account and also update my profile link as I want (like Facebook and LinkedIn).

Comment: how can I access my old account or is there any option to merge?

Comment: @PedroLobito, Participating in Meta requires 5 reputation. **Sanjoy**, Merging of accounts is a frequently asked question. *Search within the website, before asking the question*. This link might help you → [How to merge accounts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: @Raju: I know, this is a technical issue/test. ;) and thanks for the link